# How to determine when a child control is closed

Tags: c#, events, custom-controls

I am writing a program in which each page is a custom control. The problem that i have is i can't get the parent control to determine when the child control is closing. this is the code for calling the child control:

```
    public void DisplayPanel(Control c)
    {
        Cursor = Cursors.WaitCursor;
        c.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        c.Show();
        c.ControlRemoved += new ControlEventHandler(OnChildClose);
        this.Controls.Add(c);

        c.BringToFront();
        Cursor = Cursors.Default;
    }
```

and this is the event handler:

```
    public void OnChildClose(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Child closed");
        ... rest of code to redraw listview... 
    }
```

on the child control, this is how i exit it:

```
        this.Parent.Controls.Remove(this);
```

It all works, but the problem is then once the child control is finished, I need to do things like redraw a listview, but the above event doesn't fire. Is there any other way of doing this? or do I need to go upon it in another way?

What happens currently, is for example, I use the child control to add something to a database, then exit the child. The child control disappears, and the parent is left on the screen, but nothing is updated on the parent. I need to exit the parent control and go back into to see the additions to the database

Comment: You sure you want to listen for ControlRemoved on c and not this (c.Parent)?

Comment: yeah i am using .net4 winform

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure that by removing the child from the parent list, you also disconnect all event handlers, and therefore you don't get the notification the child is being closed (it's probably being closed *after* you remove it from the parent's list).

You can try not to remove it from the parent list at all, and just `Dispose` it. Or, since the child knows the parent should be refreshed, have the client send the parent a message asking the parent to refresh itself. That way you don't depend on anything implicit and know exactly what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

In child control define an `event`:

```
public delegate void RemovedEventHandler(object sender, EventArgs e);

class ChildControl
{
    ...

    public event RemovedEventHandler Removed;

    protected virtual void OnRemoved(EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Removed != null)
            Removed(this, e);
    }

    public void Remove(object value) 
    {
       // Before remove from parent call event 
       OnRemoved(EventArgs.Empty);
       //Here remove from parent
       ...
    }
}
```

and it usage in parent control:

```
  ChildControl control = ...
  control.Removed += new EventHandler(ChildRemoved);


  // This will be called whenever the Child Removed:
  private void ChildRemoved(object sender, EventArgs e) 
  {
     ChildControl childControlThatRemoved = (ChildControl) sender;
     Console.WriteLine("This is called when the Child Removed.");
  }
```

Comment: I tried adding the above code. But the parent control cant find the Removed event on the child control.

Comment: @TonyHasselbacher: I updated my answer. you must to call event before remove it!

Comment: in parent my parent code i have:
            ChildControl = new Fixture_Knockout();
            ChildControl.Removed += new EventHandler(OnChildClose);
            DisplayPanel(ChildControl);

and VS doesn't like the ChildControl.Removed bit on the parent. says it doesn't exist. both files are in the same namespace. the Child has the same code as you do